# ApplicationWindow and header overdraw

Tags: qt, qml

I wonder why I get this result

[image: Rectangle not above the header]

As you can see, the Header is above the rectangle.
When I check everything, I got `toolBar.parent === rect.parent`. So the parent is common at both. Since the parent is the same, when I do `anchors.top: parent.top` I must not get something like `anchors.top: toolBar.bottom`.

Here is my full code :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
import "EasyWidget"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow;
    visible: true;
    width: 480;
    height: 640;
    title: qsTr("Easy Music Video");

    header: ApplicationToolBar {
        id: toolBar;
        width: mainWindow.width;
        height: mainWindow.height / 8;
        title: qsTr("Music");
        onClicked: console.log("clicked");
    }

    Rectangle {
        z: 1;
        id:rect;
        color: Material.color(Material.BlueGrey);
        width: mainWindow.width / 3;

        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom;
            top: parent.top;
            left: parent.left;
            //topMargin: -toolBar.height;
        }
    }
}
```

I must use the `topMargin: -toolBar.height` to solve the problem, but I wonder why I get this result since the parent are the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows the layout:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#details

The parent is the same, but the `contentItem` is positioned below the `header`, so anchoring `rect` to the top of it won't do what you want.

To fix it, add this to your `Rectangle`:

```
topMargin: -mainWindow.header.height
```

Comment: Yes but since the parent of the header is also the contentItem... it is funny to see this behaviour ^^.
Thanks btw